Is there a maintained open-source Redis proxy similar to Twemproxy? Asked
I'm looking for a maintained open-source Redis proxy similar to Twemproxy, but with more recent commits and not so dead-looking?
I have thousands of independent pods, each maintaining at least one Redis connection, and each pod performs minimal Redis operations.
I might also check Redis Cluster, but proxy approach sounds a bit more flexible

Given your use case with thousands of independent pods and minimal Redis operations, a dedicated Redis proxy might be overkill.
I recommend starting with Redis Sentinel. It's already part of your Redis setup and can provide basic proxy functionality for read-only clients. You can monitor its performance and explore other options if needed.
